# Will it break my system (elementary OS Freya 0.3.1) if I completely remove pantheon-files?

Tags: pantheon-files

I was contemplating uninstalling pantheon-files completely from elementary OS Freya 0.3.1.. Would this action break my system? I've checked the dependencies in Synaptic Package Manager but I can't make heads or tails of what any of it means to my system. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Just for interest, why are you are trying to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Haven't try it yet, but I don't see much of a problem.

elementary OS is build on top of Ubuntu. And Ubuntu works fine without Pantheon Files :D

Just remember to install Nautilus, Dolphin or other file manager if you don't want to see your files only via terminal.

If it happens to remove other features from elementary OS, just reinstall the package `elementary-desktop`. That should reinstall all the packages needed for elementary, including the pantheon-files.

Comment: Cool, thank you for the quick reply. I'll try it and let you know if it breaks or not. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @JakeNewkirk Did it break??